# Mysql cross table update permission problem

Tags: mysql, database-permissions

I'm doing a MySQL query similar to following:

```
    UPDATE my_articles a
LEFT JOIN categorylinks cl ON a.pageid = cl.cl_from
      SET a.importance = 'High'
    WHERE cl.cl_to = 'High'
```

The problem is, I don't have a UPDATE right for the `categorylinks` table (I do have that right for `my_articles`), so the query fails with the message

```
 UPDATE command denied to user 'svick'@'willow.toolserver.org' for table 'categorylinks'
```

How can I work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it with Select inside Update.

Something like that (not tested):

```
UPDATE my_article a
SET a.importance = 'High'
WHERE a.page_id IN(SELECT cl.cl_from FROM categorylinks cl WHERE cl.cl_to='High')
```

Comment: Glad, I could help. Good luck with your project.